# How do I make a responsive div with scroll content in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
/* css */
.phone {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 3%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.phone .screen {
    height: 50%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #c3cee0;
}

.phone .nav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="phone">
  <div class="screen">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
      ...
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <p>Back</p>
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>Menu</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the phone to be responsive but in order to enable the scroll in the `div.screen` I need to set the `height` of the `div.phone`. The problem is that the `red border` is going beyond the phone's content.

I'd like the border to finish where the `div.nav` ends but I'm getting unwanted extra space. See this live [demostration](https://jsfiddle.net/t9f2rqes/5/).

---

**TL;DR**

Live [demostration](https://jsfiddle.net/t9f2rqes/5/).
I need to set a `height` (for `div.phone`) in order to enable the `scroll` for the text messages but then I get that extra space shown by the red border. How can I make `div.phone` (red border) be the same height of the whole content (without the extra space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using `display: flex`. Live [demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/t9f2rqes/9/).

Basically

```
.phone {
    height: 50%; /* whatever height you need */

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* used to separate the divs vertically */
                            /* instead of horizontally */
    border-radius: 3%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.phone .screen {
    flex: 9; /* screen will take 9/10 spaces from the div.phone */
    overflow-y: auto; /* enables scroll */
}

.phone .nav {
    flex: 1; /* nav will take 1/10 spaces from the div.phone */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height using calc().

```
.phone .screen{
   height: calc(100% - 33px);
 }
```

33px is the height of bottom nav.

Comment: This is close to solving the issue. The `.nav` is responsive too, so its height won't always be 33px.

Comment: Use media queries for solving this.

Comment: is this issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution you need to remove height:100% prperty from .phone and define height in px in .phone .screen so it will work fine

Here is updated css

```
.phone {
    height:auto;
}
.phone .screen {
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #c3cee0;
}
```

And here is [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t9f2rqes/6/)

Comment: It fix the border but then the `phone` would stop being responsive.

Comment: It still doesn't fix the problem. Try changing the width of your browser.

Comment: Yes i tried and it`s working fine What you face actually problem width..?